# How can I create a new doc in Illustrator without an artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, artboard

I do not always want to use artboards in Illustrator.

I have either changed a setting or preference somewhere recently or the default of "1 artboard" is new to the latest release of CC2015.

When I place a illustration (from Illustrator) into InDesign it wants to place the entire artboard.

Comment: Every Illustrator document has to have at least 1 artboard. So what is the issue you're placing Illustrator files into InDesign? Do you have graphics outside of the artboard?

Comment: You can't have less than 1 artboard and it's definitely not new since I still use CS6. What's the issue you're having exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You can **not** create an Illustrator document *without* an artboard. **All** Illustrator files have at least 1 artboard.

However... to deal with your InDesign issue.... when choosing `Place`, tick the `Show Import Options` box (in the InDesign Place dialog window) and *then* find the Illustrator file and click `OK`.

[image]

Then a second dialog will pop up allowing you to choose *what* you want to import, for example, you can choose to crop the import to just the `Art` as opposed to the `Media` (artboard).

[image]

This allows you to import the Illustrator artwork into InDesign based upon the *artwork* bounds, rather than the *artboard* size.